# When "tesseract box.train",the result is "Error during processing."

Tags: macos, tesseract

## MAC10.11.3  tesseract3.05.00dev

> I am using tesseract to recognize the word which from 12306.cn. I try to take the following steps:

- 1、Merging tif by jTessBoxEditor's tool.
- 2、makebox from Chinese(chi_sim):`$ tesseract chi_sim.12306.exp0.tif chi_sim.12306.exp0 -l chi_sim batch.nochop cakebox`.
- 3、generate tr:`$ tesseract chi_sim.12306.exp0.tif chi_sim.12306.exp0 nobatch box.train`.

> But When I move to the 3rd step，i meet en error "Error during processing."without any extra hints.The shell screenshot is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5c0J.png) and my tif such like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIjAb.png).It is strange that when I change some of the source tif(I have 100,000+tif) to merge a new tif,I can succeed.But I want to know and need to know the reason.Thanks for your help.